How to install Windows LAPS schema extensions on AWS Directory Services AD?
I would like to use Windows LAPS to manage local admin account passwords for Windows servers part of an active directory domain hosted by AWS Directory Services. The Update-LapsADSchema PowerShell cmdlet can't be used, because AWS doesn't allow AD schema modifications this way.  The only supported way is to provide an LDIF file in AWS Directory Services management console.
Where can I get an LDIF file template for Windows LAPS AD schema changes?
Thank you

Looks like all you need to know about the schema changes can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/laps/laps-technical-reference
I would include a snippet of the changes, but it's probably too voluminous to include as a part of the answer.  IN short, you'll be adding these schema elements:
msLAPS-PasswordExpirationTime
msLAPS-Password
msLAPS-EncryptedPassword
msLAPS-EncryptedPasswordHistory
msLAPS-EncryptedDSRMPassword
msLAPS-EncryptedDSRMPasswordHistory


For the future people who may stumble across this answer but find the link doesn't work, I just DuckDuckGo'ed "Update-LapsADSchema LDIF" and the second or third hit was the reference article from Microsoft.
